# Random values ​in selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Selenium, and I can't quite figure out how to insert random values to a `Send.Key` in a `findElement`. I'm using Selenium web driver with Java.

Here's my code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).click();
    {
        int T;
        double M=0;
        boolean S = true;
        boolean x = false;
        double p = 1;
        for (T = 0; T == (int) Math.floor(T / 10);)
            p = (p + T % 10 * (9 - M++ % 6)) % 11;
        //return S?S-1:'k';


        alert(x ? p - 1 : 'k');

        double alert;
        driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).sendKeys(alert);

    }
```

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: What language is running selenium? Java?

Comment: _to insert random values_: _`alert(x ? p - 1 : 'k')`_ possibly generates a pattern. What error do you see?

Comment: what are your bounds?  (include letters, numbers, extended characters?, min-length, max-length?)

Comment: @code It's Java sir

Comment: @undetectedSelenium Is that: "java: method sendKeys in interface org.openqa.selenium.WebElement cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.CharSequence[]
  found:    double
  reason: varargs mismatch; double cannot be converted to java.lang.CharSequence"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).click();       


 String Capital_chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            String Small_chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            String numbers = "0123456789";
    int length = 8; // You can change the lenght of the random string as per your requirement
    String values = Capital_chars + Small_chars + numbers ;
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();  
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    
                  // generate random index number
                  int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(values.length());
    
                  // get character specified by index
                  // from the string
                  char randomChar = values.charAt(index);
    
                  // append the character to string builder
                  sb.append(randomChar);
                }
            System.out.println("sb===="+sb.toString()); 

driver.findElement(By.id("id1")).sendKeys(sb.toString());
```